# Is it possible to check if Email/Pass credentials are valid without log in in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Hi I have credentials like this

```
let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: email, password: password)
```

and I want to check if are they valid before I log in an user.
I need to check it because I want to link the annonymous account before I log in to a provided one.

Comment: Looking at the docs it seems you can only re-authenticate with credentials and only authenticate by signing in.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to merge an existing email/password account with an anonymous one? If you so, you can't link 2 existing accounts with different UIDs. You would need to merge manually (and drop one of the users). To check the account is valid without losing the anonymous user after sign in, you can always create a temp copy of a Firebase app with the same plist config and then sign in to that with that email/pass credential. If it succeeds, the credential is valid and you can manually merge both currentUsers on each App instance.